# Highlight XML errors based on this XML file's XML Schema

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-xml

I have an XML file that must conform to a particular [XML Schema](http://www.w3.org/XML/Schema):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<myroot
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="/home/nico/schemas/myroot.xsd">
    <blabla />
</myroot>
```

When I edit this XML file in Vim, I would like to be told whether the syntax is OK, for instance by showing `<blabla />` in red if it is not allowed by the XML Schema.

Most IDEs do that by default. Is it achievable with Vim?

If needed, I am OK with doing some particular configuration for this XML/XML Schema, as I edit this particular XML file very often. It is about a megabyte.

Comment: Vim isn't good at semantic highlighting -- instead, it's purely based on regular expressions. But a plugin like [Syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) could show you errors when you save the file, provided you have the necessary external programs to validate XML.

Comment: @tommcdo: Looks nice! If anyone know a Syntastic-compatible XML Schema-based XML validator (not just an XML validator), then it would make for a fantastic answer :-)

Answer (score 3):

xmllint supports local schema validation, so with Syntastic + xmllint you can accomplish what you want.

Once installing both tools, add the following autocmd to your vimrc, tweaking paths to match where the files actually live:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead /home/nico/xml/commonly_edited.xml call s:xml_validate()
function! s:xml_validate()
    let g:syntastic_xml_xmllint_args = "--schema /home/nico/schemas/test.xsd"
endfun
```

This will cause xmllint to obey the schema when validating, and tag errors in the signs column on save, as seen here:

[image: xml schema validation example]

Alternatively, there are alternate syntax validators such as [Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/), which can supposedly validate based on the schemas defined inside the file directly, instead of having to manually specify. One could possibly write a Syntastic checker that uses Xerces to validate XML, but that could be a bit more involved if it doesn't spit errors out in the right format.

Answer (score 2):

The [Syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) plugin currently contains support for xmllint from [xmlsoft](http://www.xmlsoft.org). If you know of another xml lint checker that verifies schema or dtd then it will be your easiest bet to create a Syntastic plugin for it.